# Is [students] a meta-tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

On Stack Overflow, the [students](/questions/tagged/students) tag defines context and describes nothing about the question itself. So is it a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for Stack Overflow and should it be removed?

The tag wiki excerpt for [student](/questions/tagged/student) is:

> This tag is OBSOLETE and is in the process of being removed. Please do
> NOT add this tag to questions. But don't remove it without looking at
> the question to see if it needs cleanup.

I guess same applies for [students](/questions/tagged/students) too.

Comment: The tag doesn't describe some subject that is on-topic to SO, and it has multiple interpretations, so it should be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree.

Given that is was often accompanied by the deprecated [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag, I have gone through the list of 40 or so [students](/questions/tagged/students) questions and edited them into shape where possible. (Or voted to see many of them closed).

In no case did I find the [students](/questions/tagged/students) tag to be necessary. So I would agree that it does no longer need to be there. And after my editing there are no longer any such questions with that tag. Which should mean that within a day or so this tag will no longer exist.